# call other javascript function from other jsp/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have 2 html files that have the functions as below:

```
A.html
function A(){
...
window.location.href = "B.html";
}

B.html
function B(){
...
}
```

I would like to direct to B.html from A.html and call function B directly. How can I achieved that?. Since I want to pass JSON String from function A to function B, instead of using window.onload() or $(document).ready().

I store my JSON String to local storage, and direct the user to B.html. Then function B will read local storage and process data directly.

Comment: Put both the functions in one file and include the file in both pages

Comment: You'd have to persist in some way whatever information you want to pass along (even if that information is simply a flag indicating that `B()` should be executed).  Simple information could be on the query string (for example: `B.html?runB=true`), more complex information could be stored in local storage or a cookie or something of that nature.  On `B.html`, you would have code which looks for this information (wherever you ended up putting it) and responds accordingly.

Comment: Hmm...I have thought about that, since I build 2 modules in different pages, it involves a lot of data passing,function calling and DOM. I don't want to mess up the modules...any suggestion?

Comment: @David ya, I store my JSON String to local storage and then direct user to B.html and function B start to read local storage and process the data...

Comment: @helloworld1234: Then what's the problem?  That sounds like exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: @David the problem is when direct to B.html, how could I call function B? Since window.onload()/ $(document).ready() already call other function and process data. It will have conflict for my module if call function B in ready to load...

Comment: @helloworld1234: You'd call the function by, well, calling the function: `B();`  Why are there "conflicts"?  What's the *actual problem*?  At the moment you're just asking how to call a function, which is just: `B();`

Comment: @David So, you means I should load function by using window.onload()/ $(document).ready()?

Comment: @helloworld1234: I didn't say that, nor is it at all clear why that would be necessary given the information in the question.  You are *literally* asking how to run your `B` function.  This is how you do it: `B();`  Did you *try*?  What didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply POST any kind of data from one page to another with data without a suitable backend.

Option 1: Define RESTful routes
You need to define a third page/uri C that is responsible for only setting the JSON. And perhaps a fourth page/uri D that is responsible for outputting the JSON.

Then you can separate concerns and redirect from A to B after A has called C to set the JSON. And B will call D to get the JSON that was set by A.

Option 2: Storage (RESTful routes optional as well)
You could alternatively use a database, flat file, or session to achieve the same results, depending on your backend.